# Display linked list inline

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to display linked list elements inline instead of having it in a new line.

I originally thought because I had `/n` and `endl` it was displaying in a new line, so I removed them and they still display in a new line.

```
// display function
    void display()
    {
        Node*current = head;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            cout << "Queue";
            cout << current->value << " ";
            cout << endl;
            current = current->next;
        }


    }

// adding to queue function
void enqueue(int num) {

        Node *node = new Node(num);
        cout << "Pushing: " << num << endl;
        if (tail != NULL)
        {
            tail->next = node;
        }
        tail = node;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = node;
        }
        display();

    }
```

Every time I push something to the queue it will display the value that is being pushed, and what is currently being stored in the queue.
What is being printed every time I push something

```
// Results
Pushing 1
Queue: 1
Pushing 2 
Queue: 2
Pushing 3
Queue: 3

// What I want to display
Pushing 1
Queue: 1
Pushing 2
Queue: 1 2
Pushing 3
Queue: 1 2 3
```

Comment: `endl` is printing a new line and flushing your stream, did you remove them from everywhere? I see atleast two places.

Comment: Is the newline your problem, or the fact that only the last element of your queue gets printed? If you just move the `cout << endl` behind the loop, it [should work](https://ideone.com/LXRwP9). Are `head` and `tail` global variables?

Comment: I don't think your head node is doing what you think. With the endl in your display function, I'd expect the output to be (after pushing 3 nodes)  "Pushing 3 \n Queue: 1 \n Queue: 2 \n Queue: 3", but I think your head node is being set to the node you just enqueued. So your list is only ever 1 node long.

Comment: _"so I removed them"_ `cout << endl;` ...

Comment: Take a few minutes and think about what it means to have `cout << "Queue";` and `cout << endl;` inside the loop.

Comment: @molbdnilo haha I am dumb I figured it out thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Put `cout<<endl` outside the loop:

```
void display()
{
    Node*current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        cout << "Queue";
        cout << current->value << " ";
        current = current->next;
    }

    cout << endl;

}
```